# wysiwyg gwt/gxt which can import image

Tags: java, gwt, wysiwyg, gxt

I'm on a project with

```
<jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
<gwt.version>2.5.1</gwt.version>
<gxt.version>2.3.0-gwt22</gxt.version>
```

I can't upgrade.

I look for a WYSIWYG which can import image

I try 
https://www.tinymce.com/

A GWT version of tinymce is available for GWT, but not working with my GWT version. ( The toolbar is not displayed for unknow reason )

I try CKEditor, not working too
[How to integrate CKEditor in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958728/how-to-integrate-ckeditor-in-gwt)

The GXT component HtmlEditor work, but doesn't have image support.

Is there a wysiwyg compatible with my configuration with image support ?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is to use RichTextArea
It has a

```
void insertImage(String url)
```

method in it's javadoc, as well as basic rich editing. You can develop the toolbar by yourself, and add a small legend somewhere about default shortcuts (Ctrl+B, Ctrl+I ...) to make sure the user knows how to use those.

For CKEditor issue - you need to post some code, so we can help you